# ssh in LG WebOS tv with pty allocation request failed on chanel 0

Tags: ssh, webos, lg

I can access my lg web OS server through SFTP, But I want to access the server from terminal in ssh, It will raise the error

```
ssh -i .ssh/tv43_webos prisoner@192.168.1.2 -p 9922                                                                                               jwtiyar@ArcJwtiyar
Enter passphrase for key '.ssh/tv43_webos':
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

mounting and unmounting not working as suggested by some users:

```
sudo mount devpts /dev/pts -t devpts
```

Iam using Archlinux.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `-T` flag:

> If an interactive session is requested ssh by default will only request a pseudo-terminal (pty) for interactive sessions when the client has one.  The flags -T and -t can be used to override this behaviour.

```bash
ssh -i .ssh/tv43_webos prisoner@192.168.1.2 -p 9922 -T
```